# When do citizens of a new city adopt a religion?

Tags: civilization-6

I have settled a relatively new city with 11 citizens and it has had a Holy Site from early in its founding. It has my pantheon, but no followers of any religion shows when using the religion lens on the map. Does spreading with a religious unit have any effect on the city? When, under what conditions, will its citizens get religion?

Here is an image from the map. The city in question is at top-center: https://i.gyazo.com/767d76276e2643bb4606499f9a0d51a9.jpg

Note: A turn or two later, the citizens became members of religions. I am not sure what triggered this development. Perhaps my asking the question here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are basically 2 sources of religious conversion in Civ:

1. Religious units doing their conversion action on your city
2. Religious pressure from other cities

Religious pressure is most likely what happened here. Religious pressure comes from nearby cities passively converting citizens of other cities to their religion. The closer the city the more pressure (I think the range is up to 10 tiles or so).

Note that having faith buildings such as holy sites does *not* inherently make your citizens religious.